# Creating Dummy Variables from List

Tags: r, dummy-data

So I'm trying to create dummy variables to attach to a data frame based on whether or not a specific column of the frame has specific words in it. The column would look something like this:

```
 dumcol = c("good night moon", "good night room", "good morning room", "hello moon")
```

and I'd be creating dummy variables based on which words are contained in each row, e.g. for the first one, it contains `"good", "night",` and `"moon"`, but not `"room", "morning"` or `"hello"`.

The way I've been going about it so far, in a hugely primitive way, is creating a 0-valued matrix of appropriate size, and then using a for loop like so:

```
result=matrix(ncol=6,nrow=4)
wordlist=unique(unlist(strsplit(dumcal, " ")))
for (i in 1:6)
{ result[grep(wordlist[i], dumcol),i] = 1 }
```

or something similar. I'm guessing there's a faster/more resource efficient way to do it. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(tm)
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(dumcol))
myTDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(minWordLength = 1))
as.matrix(myTDM)
```

Which gives:

```
#         Docs
#Terms     1 2 3 4
#  good    1 1 1 0
#  hello   0 0 0 1
#  moon    1 0 0 1
#  morning 0 0 1 0
#  night   1 1 0 0
#  room    0 1 1 0
```

If you want the dummy variables in columns, you could use `DocumentTermMatrix` instead:

```
#    Terms
#Docs good hello moon morning night room
#   1    1     0    1       0     1    0
#   2    1     0    0       0     1    1
#   3    1     0    0       1     0    1
#   4    0     1    1       0     0    0
```

Comment: Never heard of that package, but I bet it has a lot of tools for the OP's other tasks.

Comment: Yeah, I've used tm before, it's what I use for word-associations as well. I'm pretty new to it, so learning about its different functions is really helpful.

@Steven, does tm treat the DTM as an object that I can attach to a dataframe using cbind? I've had problems with how functions from tm output the data.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 library(qdapTools)
 mtabulate(strsplit(dumcol, ' '))
 #    good hello moon morning night room
 #1    1     0    1       0     1    0
 #2    1     0    0       0     1    1
 #3    1     0    0       1     0    1
 #4    0     1    1       0     0    0
```

Or

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 cSplit_e(as.data.frame(dumcol), 'dumcol', sep=' ', 
                      type='character', fill=0, drop=TRUE)
 #  dumcol_good dumcol_hello dumcol_moon dumcol_morning dumcol_night dumcol_room
 #1           1            0           1              0            1           0
 #2           1            0           0              0            1           1
 #3           1            0           0              1            0           1
 #4           0            1           1              0            0           0
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do

```
sdum <- strsplit(dumcol," ")
us   <- unique(unlist(sdum))
res  <- sapply(sdum,function(x)table(factor(x,levels=us)))
#         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# good       1    1    1    0
# night      1    1    0    0
# moon       1    0    0    1
# room       0    1    1    0
# morning    0    0    1    0
# hello      0    0    0    1
```

The result can be transposed with `t(res)` for the dummy variables in columns (the R convention).

Comment: Thanks! This will definitely work, but I might try one of the other solutions because I can use the results for other things as well.